# How to catch KeyboardInterrupt when using blocking functions in Python

Tags: python, sockets, blocking, function-call, keyboardinterrupt

I wanted to create a Python script that serves a connection until interrupted by Ctrl+C, but it simply does not work if a connection does not happen in the first place.

Simplified problem code:

```
...

try:
    conn, ADDR = listening_socket.accept() # Blocks, which is probably the problem.
    while True:
        # This code is never reached.
        ...
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # Handle the interrupt (that does not happen).
    ...
```

I am guessing the issue is that socket.accept() blocks, in which case there will be multiple spots in the while loop that will also ignore interrupts. Are there any ways to make this work like I would like it to?

Comment: Maybe try something with [signal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) or [faulthandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/faulthandler.html)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, wwii. I ended up sidestepping the issue entirely.